# What could cause a router to intermittently fail, while socket connections that haven't been intentionally closed keep working?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I pay for internet through a shared building network and often the internet will fail. What's odd is that socket connections that remain open continue working. Web browsing fails, speed tests fail, but if I'm in an online game session, until that game ends, the online interaction continues seamlessly, even while speed tests continually fail. YouTube mysteriously also continues to work, even on videos that I've never played before. Other video streaming sites don't keep working.

The ISP has failed over and over to figure this one out. I used to work tier 2 support for an ISP and I've even been trained in advanced network engineering and I can't think of what would cause this. I wonder if any of you gurus out there know what the problem could be.

Comment: Do you supply your own router at your apartment's Internet connection?  If so, try connecting your computer directly to the Apartment Internet connection and see if that is more stable. Try updating the firmware on your router.  Does the router in question belong to the landlord?  Encourage the landlord to update the building's main router firmware.

Comment: @John it's the ISP's, Im just more curious fundamentally, it terms of IPV4 tech how it happens

Comment: I would report this to the ISP, and also try a direct connection to the Apartment Internet connection.